# TypeError keeps getting thrown

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, iteration

Can someone help me out.  Everytime I run this code I get

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rygra\Documents\Ryan Projects\totalwine-product-details-scraper\products.py", line 24, in 
for r in data['product']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I had it running once for a few lines of code before it broke, now it wont run at all

```
from selectorlib import Extractor
import requests 
import csv

e = Extractor.from_yaml_file('totalwine_scrape.yml')

def scrape(url):    
    headers = {
        'authority': 'www.totalwine.com',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'referer': 'https://www.totalwine.com',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return e.extract(r.text, base_url=url)

with open("urls.txt",'r') as urllist, open('data.csv','w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=["product_name","product_image","product_desc","product_company","product_country","product_type","product_abv","product_taste"],quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writeheader()
    for url in urllist.read().splitlines():
        data = scrape(url) 
        for r in data:
            writer.writerow(r)
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because the sample code is linked externally. Please [edit] this question to include your code directly in your question. Code linked externally may not be permanently available, and may not be licensed such that it can be used in answers.

Comment: If you delete the line `for r in data['product']` and all following lines, you won't get this error.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller How am I supposed to include all the files for this to run by posting it all?

Comment: @RyanGrant You shouldn't - you should post a [mre] instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.